# Not showing @Override above methods in netbeans

Tags: java, overriding, netbeans-7

I'm using the latest version of Netbeans and after implementing MouseListener (or any Listener for the matter), I've noticed that it doesn't display `@Override` about the methods. Is there a way to actually have that written automatically

Comment: How have you generated the overriding method declaration? By typing it? Or by using the *override/implement method* wizard?

Comment: netbeans sometimes doesn't add `@Override` annotation automatically. So go to the line where you have actually overridden the method and press `ALT + Enter` and i think you might see add override annotation popup.